# Integrating Hikari Pool in Jooq

Tags: mysql, database, java-8, jooq

I am trying to use jooq first time in my current project (which is being written in Java). I want to integrate Hikari connection pool in Jooq DSL context. I want to explicitly define max number of connection. Any recommended article, code which I can follow to get through it.

Thanks

I set up jooq already and now I am able to generate code for my database.

```
   public  static void init() {

        Target l_target =   new Target();
        System.out.println("My directory is::"+l_target.getPackageName());
        l_target.setDirectory("src/main/java");
        l_target.setPackageName("com.my.paas.css.entity");
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
                .withJdbc(new Jdbc()
                        .withDriver("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
                        .withUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/paas")
                        .withUser("root"))
                .withGenerator(new Generator()
                        .withDatabase(new Database()
                                .withName("org.jooq.meta.mysql.MySQLDatabase")
                                .withIncludes(".*")
                                .withExcludes("")
                                .withInputSchema("paas"))
                        .withTarget(l_target));

        try {
            GenerationTool.generate(configuration);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

One way to go is to use one `org.jooq.impl.DSL`'s overloaded factory methods that accepts a `javax.sql.DataSource` to construct your `org.jooq.DSLContext`:

- [`using(DataSource datasource, SQLDialect dialect)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.11.x/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#using-javax.sql.DataSource-org.jooq.SQLDialect-)
- [`using(DataSource datasource, SQLDialect dialect, Settings settings)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.11.x/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#using-javax.sql.DataSource-org.jooq.SQLDialect-org.jooq.conf.Settings-)

That might look something like this:

```
final HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
config.setMinimumIdle(...);
config.setMaximumPoolSize(...);
// ...etc - whatever other pool behavior you desire

final HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);

final DSLContext dslContext = DSL.using(dataSource, SQLDialect.MYSQL)
```

Comment: Jooq will handle connection close and open by self ?

Comment: that's what the `DataSource` is for

Comment: @SandeepPandey: Yes, jOOQ will auto close connections when you pass it a `DataSource`, see: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/connection-vs-datasource